# Does Jmeter 2.11 supports pdf editor

Tags: jmeter

Does Jmeter 2.11 supports pdf editor's data capture?. Kindly anyone advice, how to record pdf data using jmeter 2.11 version. Because our application made up on java and its a web application.

The issue is,

1. Log in to the application
2. Click on user information link
3. The request will be opened in a pdf editor format, where we are updating user information.

Here is the issue, I can not record the pdf editor information. While recording, the pdf editor page is not even opened. I tried to disable my antivirus protection too.. :(

Comment: What is PDF Editor ? could you point to some link on the software ?

Comment: A pdf will be previewed in a HTML page of a IE browser, and that pdf is a editable one. Where we could edit and submit the data.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is designed to functionally test server-side components, whereas opening a PDF occurs on the client-side, albeit after the PDF has been transmitted over the wire to the end-user's browser.

As such, JMeter will only show you:

1. How long it took the server to process the request and begin serving up the response (PDF) to the browser/JMeter
2. How long it took to transmit the response (PDF) over the wire back to the browser/JMeter

If you're interested in physically manipulating items on the client-side, which also has the effect of thereby testing the server, check out http://docs.seleniumhq.org/